# Android Ksoap fault string problem

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I am using following code for a web service call using KSOAP.

```
 private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.tempuri.org/GetAuthenticateUser";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetAuthenticateUser";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://stage.mysite.com/FinancialSnapshotService/Service.asmx?WSDL";
   // I have tried http://stage.mysite.com/FinancialSnapshotService/Service.asmx also

    public void getResults() {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("vstrUserID", "vk@gmail.com");
        request.addProperty("vstrPassword", "password");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


        HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            aht.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);

            SoapObject result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();


            Log.d("WS", String.valueOf(result));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Although the web service is perfectly OK (because it is working fine for Iphone app), I am getting error:

```
05-03 16:47:49.427: WARN/ActivityManager(1194): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{45cc0980 ksoap2app.main/.Ksoap2App}
05-03 16:47:49.821: WARN/System.err(4055): SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://www.tempuri.org/GetAuthenticateUser.' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@45927830
05-03 16:47:49.831: WARN/System.err(4055):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:112)
05-03 16:47:49.831: WARN/System.err(4055):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:137)
05-03 16:47:49.831: WARN/System.err(4055):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63)
05-03 16:47:49.831: WARN/System.err(4055):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:100)
05-03 16:47:49.831: WARN/System.err(4055):     at ksoap2app.main.Ksoap2App.getResults(Ksoap2App.java:44)
05-03 16:47:49.831: WARN/System.err(4055):     at ksoap2app.main.Ksoap2App.onCreate(Ksoap2App.java:23)
05-03 16:47:49.831: WARN/System.err(4055):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-03 16:47:49.841: WARN/System.err(4055):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
05-03 16:47:49.841: WARN/System.err(4055):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
05-03 16:47:49.841: WARN/System.err(4055):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-03 16:47:49.841: WARN/System.err(4055):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
05-03 16:47:49.841: WARN/System.err(4055):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-03 16:47:49.841: WARN/System.err(4055):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-03 16:47:49.841: WARN/System.err(4055):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
05-03 16:47:49.841: WARN/System.err(4055):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 16:47:49.841: WARN/System.err(4055):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-03 16:47:49.851: WARN/System.err(4055):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-03 16:47:49.851: WARN/System.err(4055):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-03 16:47:49.851: WARN/System.err(4055):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is the problem in my code?

Comment: Please check whether the web service is correctly running or not.

Comment: check this link and make sure you put the things correctly... http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-android/index.html

Comment: Change your url from `http://stage.digitalavenues.com/C6FinancialSnapshotService/Service.asmx?WSDL` to **http://stage.digitalavenues.com/C6FinancialSnapshotService/Service.asmx** then try it again.

Comment: I have tried that also...its giving same result

Comment: Change lines 'SoapObject result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();' to `SoapObject result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn; String response = result.getProperty(0).to String`

Comment: I have tried that also. it is giving "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.SoapFault".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have changed the Variables like that:

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetAuthenticateUser";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetAuthenticateUser";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://stage.mysite.com/FinancialSnapshotServic/Service.asmx";
```

It solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Also if you are working on local host use 10.0.2.2

[How to connect to my http://localhost web server from Android Emulator in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator-in-eclips)

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to [dev_android](https://stackoverflow.com/users/525004/dev-android) answer. I was getting this error about fault SOAPAction, and my mistake was that SOAP_ACTION url was different from NAMESPACE url. They should be the **same**.

```
$NameSpaceUrl = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = $NameSpaceUrl . "GetAuthenticateUser";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetAuthenticateUser";
private static final String NAMESPACE = $NameSpaceUrl;
private static final String URL = "http://stage.mysite.com/FinancialSnapshotServic/Service.asmx";
```