# Receiving data from Android in a ASP.NET web site

Tags: android, asp.net

I wrote an Android app that sends data to an ASP.NET web site. When I test the app, I get the error:

> Connection to `https://localhost:1863` refused.

How do I solve this problem? Also, how do I go about storing this data into [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server)?

```
HttpClient client1 = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost:1863");

String lat = "lat",lng = "lng";

List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", lat));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng", lng));
try {
    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
    UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
    request.setEntity(formEntity);
    // request.addHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    HttpResponse response;
    response = client1.execute(request);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    String line;
    String page = "";
    line = in.readLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        page = page + line;
        line = in.readLine();
    }
}
catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) of your server, rather than using `localhost`, since `localhost` is local to the calling computer, so the `localhost` for the Android is different than for the IIS server.

**UPDATE:**

Just use IP address `10.0.2.2`, as explained in Stack Overflow question *[How to connect to my http://localhost web server from Android Emulator in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220)*.

Comment: ok  but i test web site with asp development server on my computer and android on the emulater in the same computer

Answer (score -1):

I made an ASP.NET handler page (.ashx), named it `Handler`, and replaced "http://localhost:1863"with"http://localhost:1863/Handler.ashx" and it solved the problem.