# Android: connecting mysql(XAMPP) to android app on emulator

Tags: android, mysql, listactivity

I'm trying to develop an android application for my final year project and i'm at the point where I need to connect a database to my application. I have previously connected to internal and external SQLite database but my supervisor says that I must use the XAMPP localhost so it would be justifiable later as it is very similar to a real life situation where a web server would be used. 
Here is the code for my DBHelper class, that i adapted from a sample code I found over the net and did change a few things but i'm quite sure there is a ton of errors. 
When the button to view the data, which would lead to this class is pressed, it would just show a blank screen and after a long while would crash.

```
package com.example.parking_guide;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DBHelper extends ListActivity {


    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static final String url_all_products = "http://10.0.0.2/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    private static final String KEY_VACANT = "vacancy";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray table = null;  

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListView yourListView = getListView();



        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    }
    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("Level1: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    table = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < table.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = table.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String _id = c.getString(KEY_ROWID);
                        String vacant = c.getString(KEY_VACANT);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(KEY_ROWID, _id);
                        map.put(KEY_VACANT, vacant);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } 
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }


        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            DBHelper.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
                                    KEY_VACANT},
                            new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.vac});
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }


    }
}
```

So i don't really know what's wrong as i'm not that good at android and just learning as I go on. Anyone who can help me?

Comment: We need the logcat output to be able to help you.

Comment: well thanks for the response guys! already solved it on my own :) it was the silliest thing though!!! thnx again

Comment: It's better if you could answer your own question, explaining how you solved it. Then the people who visit this question will benefit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect to my http://localhost web server from Android Emulator in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator-in-eclips)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use 10.0.2.2 to acces your localhost, not 10.0.0.2 :) 
http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Comment: It has been ages since I posted this on here but I think, I think!!! this was the issue back then as well! thanks for the response either way

Comment: it's nothing, it was just on top of unanswered questions so i replied :)

Comment: Hi Onur A, If my localhost at http://localhost:8081/phpmyadmin/ . So my 10.0.2.2 should remain the same or need to add 10.0.2.2:8081 ?

Comment: it has been ages but maybe someone needs the answer, you should add port of course. you can access it via 10.0.2.2:8081.