# Connect android application to Xampp server

Tags: android

---

Hello , i'm trying to register a user from an android application.
I installed Xampp, I created my database, I made a php page that will be called to save the data in the database.and when I put  the url  http://192.168.xx/ah_login_api/ to acces to my php file .An  Exception type: "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" at $ android.StrictMode AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork

I do not understand where does the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an [**AsyncTask**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to do all your network operations.

Your network operation can take a lot of time and the UI would get unresponsive if it is done on the main UI thread. And if your UI freezes for a long time, the app might get killed by the OS.

Thus Android 4+ makes it mandatory to use a background thread to perform network operations.

Put the code to do the network activity inside **`doInBackground()`** and all the AsyncTask using **`execute()`**.

Here is how your AsyncTask would look like :

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
     protected void doInBackground() {
        sendEmail();
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate() {
    //called when the background task makes any progress
 }

  protected void onPreExecute() {
     //called before doInBackground() is started
 }
 protected void onPostExecute() {
     //called after doInBackground() has finished 
 }
  }
```

And you can call it anywhere using **`new MyAsyncTask().execute("");`**

Comment: about the url to he xampp server ?? what is the true url ?

Comment: NetworkOnMainThread exception has nothing to do with the URL.

Comment: my question is  : what i must put on the url to acces to my php file in xampp server ?

Comment: Oh, try `10.0.2.2` as the IP of the localhost, assuming that you are testing on the emulator.

Comment: sorry i don't know how can i do that :

Comment: i used this code to connect to server

Comment: What errors are you facing now ? Have a look at this post..it looks good to me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720254/android-connecting-mysqlxampp-to-android-app-on-emulator

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an AsyncTask for newtwork operations , because running long operations on the main thread can make lags to your ui or even make it non responsive .

Although it is best to use AsyncTask , you can also just use an another thread

Like :

```
Thread xamp = new Thread(){

public void run(){
//Your network operation here
}

};
xamp.start();
```

Refs : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: about the url to he xampp server ?? what is the true url ?

Comment: @user2363546 , Your url to the specific file sucha as : http://127.0.0.1/project1/register.php