# Tomcat not working on Localhost

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I have an Android application that connects to a servlet in a Tomcat server.

I have Tomcat server coupled to eclipse.

The IP address indicated to the Android application to connect to the Tomcat servlet is

```
http://10.0.2.2:8080/Middleware/UsuarioServlet
```

Why if I put

```
http://localhost:8080/Middleware/UsuarioServlet
```

not work and gives an error? If I have installed Tomcat on the same machine should work with localhost too.

Comment: Have a look at this question ->
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator-in-eclips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your Android application runs on virtual device, which has another IP in your local intranet, it isn't `localhost`.

Answer (score 1):

Localhost refers to the Android device in this case. Use the IP address 10.0.2.2 to refers to your development machine. Read more about [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)!