# Testing the server side code before deploying

Tags: android, networking, network-programming, server-side

I need to send an image file from the mobile to the server(where the server will save it to the hard disk). I have wrote both the android mobile part and the server side. I need to test the code before deploying to the server. Will the code work if I connect the mobile to the WI-Fi network through which I can have a LAN connection to the system? Is there any way I can test the code with out using a WI-Fi connection(ie Connecting phone to the system via the usb cable and then forming a LAN or something)? Please voice your valuable opinion in these stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was testing my server-side I didn't find any other way rather than connecting via wifi, this way it was working just fine (in your code you need to use ipv4, not localhost, just as reminder). I'm not good with network stuff, but I don't think it's possible using usb to create some kind of LAN.

Have u tried from emulator? [How to connect to my http://localhost web server from Android Emulator in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator-in-eclips)

Comment: Though this is not what I wanted really,I found that accessing server hosted in the local network through emulator is pretty easy. I am marking your answer as the correct one. Thanks a lot.