# Exposing a service running on localhost to an Android emulator?

Tags: android, asp.net, windows, rest, visual-studio-2012

I'm running a service through ASP.net/Visual Studio that's being developed in conjunction with an Android app.  When I run the service through VS, it's accessible at `http://localhost:13980/` but not `http://127.0.0.1:13980/` (which gives a "bad request - invalid hostname" 400 error).  Obviously, I can't tell the Android app to look for a service at "localhost" since that'll be pointing at itself.

I understand ([according to this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator-in-eclips)) that the Android emulator treats 10.0.2.2 as a pass-through IP address to the host machine's 127.0.0.1, so it would stand to reason that everything would come together if I a) got localhost to be properly exposed through 127.0.0.1, and b) changed the target address in the app from localhost:port to 10.0.2.2:port.

How would I go about doing part A?  I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro, Visual Studio 2012, and the project in question is targeting .NET 4.5.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Run the web service under IIS instead of VS Cassini. This way you can bind the web service to your local network's IP address, e.g. `http://10.0.2.2:8081`
2. Modify the hosts file on your Android emulator to redirect localhost to your computer's IP address

The second one isn't a great solution. It may cause some conflicts with the OS and I'm not even sure Cassini would still even serve the request. Visual Studio's in-built web server (Cassini) only listens to local requests, so option (1) really is the most flexible. Plus, since you have W8 Pro [IIS is already built-in](http://www.howtogeek.com/112455/).

Comment: Can you point me to a resource that would walk me through doing that?  What I'm envisioning right now would require manual redeployment every time I update the server rather than Cassini's "hit F5 and it's going" approach, which would suck.  Is there some some sort of configuration I can do to have it be a one-click thing?

Also, would #2 actually work if the problem #1's addressing isn't resolved?

Comment: Could I make the change in the app to 10.0.2.2:8081 (ps: where'd that port come from? my service is running on :13980) and then change my computer's hosts file to redirect 127.0.0.1 to localhost, or does it not work like that?

Comment: You can set visual studio up so that when you press F5, it compiles and launches IIS instead. Here is a good step-by-step guide: http://idosql.com/2011/05/25/181/ - Can't put one here, it would be too long!

Answer (score 0):

The IP address `10.0.2.2` IP maps to the the `127.0.0.1` IP address, not to `localhost`.

From the emulator, connect to `10.0.2.2`, and then host your site on `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. That should work.

Answer (score -1):

Use the IP address 10.0.2.2 instead. See this:
[How to connect to my http://localhost web server from Android Emulator in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator-in-eclips)