# Contacting local web service from android app running on emulator

Tags: android, web-services, android-emulator

I created a REST web service (using Web API), but I have not published it yet. I want before test the communication with the Android client. So I have temporarily published the ws on my local machine and, on the same machine, I have started up the emulator in which runs my test application.

**Is there any way for communicating from app running in the emulator and the local ws?**

Answer (score 0):

```
Your qestion is not cleared to me.If you make your webservice and place your webservice locally(using wamp or xamp) then you can communicate to your WS via JSON parsing.

You should create DB_CONFIG file

define('DB_USER', "root"); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', ""); // db password (mention your db password here)
define('DB_DATABASE', "The name of your database"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', "localhost"); // db server
?>

and one DB_CONNECT file


<?php

/**
 * A class file to connect to database
 */
class DB_CONNECT {

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // closing db connection
        $this->close();
    }

    /**
     * Function to connect with database
     */
    function connect() {
        // import database connection variables
        require_once 'db_config.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());

        // Selecing database
        $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());

        // returing connection cursor
        return $con;
    }

    /**
     * Function to close db connection
     */
    function close() {
        // closing db connection
        mysql_close();
    }

}

?>


Then you can write individual php file where you can encode json and fetch the data through the url.You will also need a jsonparser class(which will connect the url with the ws) in your application.
```

Answer (score -1):

The localhost refers to the device on which the code is running, in this case the emulator.

If you want to refer to the computer which is running the Android simulator, use the IP address 10.0.2.2 instead. You can read more from...[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator-in-eclips)