# How to get ping to work inside the Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ping, porting

I'm porting an Linux C++ application to Android NDK and my app invokes `ping` to the shell to see the status of another machine for logging purposes.  On my android port this fails for `localhost`:

```
# ping -c 10 localhost
ping: unknown host localhost
```

If I give another web address that appears to send, but no response is seen:

```
# ping -c 1 google.com
PING google.com (74.125.239.136) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Is `localhost` expected to work on Android to refer back to the android itself (not the host machine running the emulator as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator-in-eclips))?  If not, is there some other way that will work?

Is `ping` expected to work on the Android emulator for Mac OSX or must I do something to allow the emulator to see the network fully?

Comment: Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator-in-eclips

Comment: @MichellBak Thanks for the link, but that is not the same question, I really want localhost, not the machine running the emulator as that question answers.

Comment: All right, wasn't sure. Your question could be a bit more specific, I think :)

Comment: Can you just `ping 127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: @fadden You are right!  I wonder why `localhost` fails but the `127.0.0.1` address works, shouldn't `localhost` resolve to `127.0.0.1`?  Regardless, I still cannot `ping` outside, such as to `google.com`, is that normal?