# Connecting to a server through android emulator

Tags: android, networking, android-emulator

In my application, I am trying to connect to a server(virtual machine) with specified host, but I keep getting the error "A server with the specified hostname could not be found", while when I connect the same server from my local machine through a browser or just ping, I am able to do that. I have modified hosts file on my local machine and also uploaded the same hosts file on `android` emulator. Does anyone have any pointers that can help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Check whether Internet Browser is able to open websites. If browser does says "offline message", then restart your emulator. It could fix your problem.

Comment: Internet browser is able to open the websites.

Comment: What is that host file that your mentioning ? Can you show up that file

Comment: you should probably look for this link it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator-in-eclips

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will probably have to configure your virtual machine to port forward a port from your host machine to the virtual machine web server

1. Configure virtual machine server: in my case Ubuntu in VirtualBox

   - Port forward via [this link](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward) or use NAT port forwarding via the networks tab
2. Ensure that the server is accessible in host machine

   - In host web browser (e.g. Chrome in my screenshot below), go to  `10.0.2.2:configuredPort` (in my case localhost:8181)
3. Start the android emulator and go to `10.0.2.2:configuredPort`

   - The special IP of 10.0.2.2 is taken from the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses) and represents your host machine

[image: My VirtualBox setup with the Android Emulator]

Edit:

If the virtual machine is bridged on the network, it should be accessible via IP / hostname if you modify the [Android hosts file](http://www.bradcurtis.com/hosts-files-and-the-google-android-emulator/).

```
127.0.0.1           localhost
192.168.0.123       virtualMachineBridgedAddress.com
10.0.2.2            hostMachineAddress.com
```