# My computer is connected over a VPN, Android emulator can't access local intranet sites

Tags: android, android-emulator, adt, eclipse-adt

I work remotely and connect to my office through a VPN client.  Every program on my computer can access the office network, browsers can connect to intranet sites (e.g. `http://myportal/`).  When I open an Android emulator up and open the browser, it cannot access any of the intranet sites.

Any idea why, or how to get it to do this?

EDIT: It seems to be able to access it via the IP just fine, so it looks like a DNS issue.  Any idea how to get the emulator to use the DNS address my connection is set up to use?

EDIT 2: I tried launching the emulator with the DNS tied to my VPN connection and that did not seem to help `emulator -avd Default -dns-server 192.16.200.100,192.16.4.2`

Comment: Did you fix this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Were you able to fix it ever?

Comment: if it's for web requests I'd sugest you to install privoxy or some similar software in your computer and issue the requests (when in debug environment) to the fake localhost as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator-in-eclips

Answer (score 4):

`Settings` > `Network & internet` > `Private DNS` > `Off`

Comment: Settings of your os on the android emulator.