# Getting null data when using new API android for testing compatibility

Tags: android, json, okhttp

I build an application that consumes JSON data, and I did a test on android device APIs 16, I use a library 'okhttp' to connect to the server, when I use the API 16 all smoothly, but when I use the API 17 and 19, data can not be displayed and only display the error log as follows:

```
04-19 16:17:38.394  14379-14411/com.example.mnafian.gambar E/Err IO﹕ java.net.UnknownHostException: http://
```

This is an example of code that I made to retrieve the data:

```java
package com.example.mnafian.gambar;

import android.media.Image;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView tv1, tv2;
    OkHttpClient clientRest = new OkHttpClient();
    String list[] = new String[100];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header_view);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_view);

        new LoadText().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class LoadText extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
            String list[] = new String[100];
            try {
                String url = "http://www.samplesite.net/omahnyewo/servicelist.php?type=kontrakan&lat=-7.9425479&long=112.6043546";

                Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url)
                        .build();

                Response response = clientRest.newCall(request).execute();
                String responsedata = response.body().string();
                JSONArray callData = new JSONArray(responsedata);

                if (callData != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < callData.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject objData = callData.getJSONObject(i);
                        String tv1 = objData.getString("nama");
                        String tv2 = objData.getString("harga");
                        list[0] = tv1;
                        list[1] = tv2;
                    }
                }


            } catch (JSONException eex) {
                Log.e("Err JSON", eex.toString());
            } catch (IOException eex) {
                Log.e("Err IO", eex.toString());
            }
            return list;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] strings) {
            super.onPostExecute(strings);
            list = strings;

            if (list.length>0){
                tv1.setText(list[0]);
                tv2.setText(list[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

no data is received with the above code, I use the library with version 2.2.0 okhttp.

Is there an error in the code that I created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error log, we can infer that the host of API you try to access is can't be identified/reached(probably dead). Probably there is problem in your internet connection or the DNS server. But, if you are using local machine please, read [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator-in-eclips). My advice is, first, try to check using internal browser to check the URI you use.

Comment: i just check url, i change that url to my IP server, and run perfectly, the problem in the DNS server maybe. thanks for your answer.