# I can not connect to server with Socket.IO-client Java

Tags: java, android, sockets

I want use [library](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java)

And I wan realize this functionality:

1. connect to my java server

   ```
   Socket socket = IO.socket("http://127.0.0.1:4444");
   socket.io().open(new Manager.OpenCallback() {
                   @Override
                   public void call(Exception err) {
                       if (err != null) {
                           Log.d("mylog", err.getMessage());
                           return;
                       }
                       Log.d("mylog", "connected");
                   }
               });
   ```
2. Send messge - I do not understand how.

   It is my server:

   ```
   public class Server {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
           System.out.println("Welcome to Server side");
           BufferedReader in = null;
           PrintWriter out= null;

           ServerSocket servers = null;
           Socket fromclient = null;

           // create server socket
           try {
               servers = new ServerSocket(4444);
           } catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println("Couldn't listen to port 4444");
               System.exit(-1);
           }

           try {
               System.out.print("Waiting for a client...");
               fromclient= servers.accept();
               System.out.println("Client connected");
           } catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println("Can't accept");
               System.exit(-1);
           }

           in  = new BufferedReader(new
                   InputStreamReader(fromclient.getInputStream()));
           out = new PrintWriter(fromclient.getOutputStream(),true);
           String         input,output;

           System.out.println("Wait for messages");
           while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
               if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) break;
               out.println("S ::: "+input);
               System.out.println(input);
           }
           out.close();
           in.close();
           fromclient.close();
           servers.close();
       }
   }
   ```

If I use Java client I can work with server, but I want to connect to android client. And I found only this library, and I not understand how it work. Examples in site not helped for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added its permission in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Android's kernel, unlike mainline Linux kernel, restricts requests for creating sockets unless that application already has INTERNET permission.

Find more technical information about Android's Paranoid networking option in this [link](http://elinux.org/Android_Security#Paranoid_network-ing).

**UPDATE #1**

If you want to connect your Android client to the server on your PC localhost you should not use `127.0.0.1` as server IP address. This is Android its own localhost. You should instead use `10.0.2.2` as server IP address. [More Info](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)

Comment: of course I have NOT forgotten to add"android.permission.INTERNET"

Comment: @Pavel So, do you want to connect from the server to your Android client?

Comment: I want connect my android client to my java server and pass String message from android client to java server

Comment: I tried it and not helped public static final String CHAT_SERVER_URL = "http://192.168.0.33";

Comment: @Pavel Where is your server running? In your computer's localhost? or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes on my computer's localhost. Standart JavaSE application

Comment: @Pavel So, First off check out if your server is listening on localhost interface. You could find out using `netstat` command. Or enter `http://localhost/` in your browser on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

@Pavel i've implemented SocketIO client for one of my app

here is the code... i think ..this may help u

```
private Socket mSocket;
/**
 * chat socket connection methods
 */
public void socketConnection()
{
    try
    {
        mSocket = IO.socket(Constant.CHAT_SERVER_URL);
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
        mSocket.on("message", onSocketConnectionListener);
        mSocket.connect();
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(mSocket.connected()==false)
            {
                //do nothing
            }
            sendConnectData();
        }
    }).start();
}

/**
 * Send Data to connect to chat server
 */
public void sendConnectData()
{
    JSONObject msgToSend=new JSONObject();
    try
    {
        msgToSend.put("Type", 1);
        msgToSend.put("userid", userid);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mSocket.emit("message", msgToSend);
}

/**
 * Listener for socket connection error.. listener registered at the time of socket connection
 */
private Emitter.Listener onConnectError = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mSocket != null)
                    if (mSocket.connected() == false)
                        socketConnection();
            }
        });
    }
};

/**
 * Listener to handle messages received from chat server of any type... Listener registered at the time of socket connected
 */
private Emitter.Listener onSocketConnectionListener = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // handle the response args
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: its simple url public static final String CHAT_SERVER_URL = "http://192.168.0.211:8000"

Comment: u can try the ip of the chat server assign by server like http://192.168.0.10:4444 or http://10.0.2.2:4444 instead of http://127.0.0.1:4444

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:4444 is not recognized if the code is run on android (if it is an android app)

Comment: I have error if tried this structure FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets/smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme at index 0: 192.168.0.33:4444

Comment: at which IDE u r working .. ? if android studio - then add dependency at your gradle file compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.5.2'

Comment: "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme at index 0:" - means add url with http://

Comment: ok Pavel.. is the chat server is on diff machine or ours? and your IDE?

Comment: Yes server run in IntellijIDEA on my computer

Comment: then use url as http://10.0.2.2:4444 for socket connection and dependency - compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.5.2' and debug or log for mSocket.connect()

Comment: I do not understand you. How can i use url as 10.0.2.2:4444 for socket connection?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator-in-eclips

Comment: CHAT_SERVER_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:4444"; not work((((( and in debug after mSocket.connect(); line mSocket.connected() - show true

Comment: mSocket.connected() == true means the socket connection b/w client & server is est.

Comment: n how can u tell that the CHAT_SERVER_URL = "10.0.2.2:4444" not working... as the socket connection is showing true

Comment: it is in debug but mSocket.connect();
        Log.d("mylog", String.valueOf(mSocket.connected())); show false

Comment: how this is possible.. it means you not debugging the app properly