# Pass local filepath to JsonArrayRequest

Tags: android, json, android-emulator

Is there a way to test android app by using local (ie computer on which emulator is running) JSON file instead of giving it URL of online file. In my university we have proxy login which means that android apps cant access the internet so i need to use a file on my system for testing app on emulator. do i need to setup a server like wamp or can i directly pass filepath as argument to JsonArrayRequest?

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a clue about other workarounds, but you can set up **Wamp Server** or **Xamp Server** and call the url from `emulator`,

And yes in order to access the `localhost` inside **Emulator** you can use following IP:

`10.0.2.2` for **Default emulator** and `10.0.3.2` for **GenyMotion**

and yes to mention i got the `GenyMotion` reference from this answer [link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24853561/2641726)