# How to test an app created with Angular CLI ng serve from another device?

Tags: networking, angular, angular-cli

I have an app generated with Angular CLI from scratch. CLI version `angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2`

I am trying to test it from my smartphone but I get **Connection refused**.

So, I run `ng serve` on my laptop and try to access the app:

- From laptop, using `localhost`: Works
- From laptop, using IP: **Connection refused**
- From smartphone, using IP: **Connection refused**

This used to work with the previous, SystemJS version of CLI. I checked that I don't have a firewall running.

How could I fix or debug this error?

I am using a Mac.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Adding the host-flag with value "0.0.0.0" should allow you to access the webserver from any device on your local network.

This should work:
`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`

For an explanation: 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/1475#issuecomment-235986121

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: this doesn't work for me. What do you put in the address bar?

Comment: it used to work.  Are you sure your issue isn't with angular-cli?  I can't finish a build.  It stalls at 70%.

Comment: solution: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1793#issuecomment-276960462

Comment: Thank you!! Thought I would have to build and deploy to server just to test CSS changes.

Comment: "ng serve -host 0.0.0.0" the way to go!

Answer (score 11):

In package.json

```
 "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0   --port 4200 --disable-host-check ",
```

However `--disable-host-check` would be a security risk
and you will need 
`"@angular/cli": "^1.1.0-rc.2"` as this flag appeared in 1.1 version

Comment: Running with `--disable-host-check` on Angular CLI version 1.2.7 emits this error: `WARNING Running a server with --disable-host-check is a security risk. See https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server-middleware-security-issues-1489d950874a for more information.`

Answer (score 2):

Following the advice on this page:
https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server-middleware-security-issues-1489d950874a, this worked for me:

`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --host my-computer`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can be helpfull (a bit automated version of @Captain Whippet's answer):

dev-server.js:

```
const os = require('os');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

function getLocalIp(ipMatchArr) {
  const networkInterfaces = os.networkInterfaces();
  let matchingIps = Object.keys(networkInterfaces).reduce((arr, name) => {
    const matchingInterface = networkInterfaces[name].find(iface =>
      iface.family === 'IPv4' && ipMatchArr.find(match => iface.address.indexOf(match) > -1));
      if (matchingInterface) arr.push(matchingInterface.address);
      return arr;
  }, []);

  if (matchingIps.length) {
    return matchingIps[0];
  }
  else {
    throw(`Error. Unable to find ip to use as public host: ipMatches=['${ipMatchArr.join("', '")}']`);
  }
}

function launchDevServer(address) {
  const port = process.env.port || 4200;
  const publicHostname = address + ":" + port;
  console.log(`[[[ Access your NG LIVE DEV server on \x1b[33m ${publicHostname} \x1b[0m ]]]`);
  spawn(
      "ng serve"
    , [
          "--host 0.0.0.0"
        , `--public ${publicHostname}`
      ]
    , { stdio: 'inherit', shell: true }
  );
}

/* execute */
launchDevServer(getLocalIp(['192.168.1.', '192.168.0.']));
```

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node dev-server.js"
  }
```

### then run "npm start"

You can then open your app on any device on your local network via address printed in yellow.

@angular/cli: 1.3.2, node: 6.9.5

tested on Mac and Windows