# how to run angular5 app from another machine?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

how to run angular5 app from another machine?

commands which I have tried

```
ng serve --host 192.168.56.1 --disable-host-check

ng serve --host 192.168.56.1

ng serve --host 0.0.0.0

ng serve --port 8080 --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck true
```

I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39069742/how-to-test-an-app-created-with-angular-cli-ng-serve-from-another-device). not helping though.
my angular/cli version : 1.5.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test an app created with Angular CLI ng serve from another device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39069742/how-to-test-an-app-created-with-angular-cli-ng-serve-from-another-device)

Answer (score 0):

If your other device is in the same network, you can access  ng serve with :

```
ng serve --port 8080 --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck true
```

value "0.0.0.0" should allow you to access the webserver from any device on your local network.

But i hope port 8080 is open on your firewall

Comment: what should I write in status bar?

Comment: Status bar ? just try: ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck true in a command line

Comment: i did tried this command. it says  "open your browser on http://localhost:8080/ **