# Fetch Api:Can not get data from localhost

Tags: android, node.js, laravel-5, nativescript, fetch-api

I have been trying to create an android app using nativescript.I am using fetch module to get response from my server.When I am trying to get response from **httpbin.org/get** ,it is OK.But when I am trying to get response from my local server,I am getting **Network Request Failed.** error.

Sending to httpbin.org/get-

```
return fetchModule.fetch("https://httpbin.org/get").then(response => { return response.text(); }).then(function (r) {
        console.log(r);
    }, function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        });
```

Sending to localhost:8000/api-

```
return fetchModule.fetch("http://localhost:8000/api").then(response => { return response.text(); }).then(function (r) {

       console.log(r);

}, function (e) {

        console.log(e);
    });
```

When I try to get response from localhost:8000/api in pure node.js via the request module.It worked fine.But now,I don't to know how to solve this in nativescript using fetch module.

Comment: Are you sure you have internet connection on mobile?

Comment: Dont use localhost as localhost point to local device in this case your mobile which isn't server. Check on your pc what is IP and change localhost for IP

Comment: Why Internet Connection? I am using AVD of Android Studio.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/5806220/3284355 localhost refers to the device(emulator) not to the IP of computer the emulator is running on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead, `localhost` (usually `127.0.0.1`) use **10.0.2.2** (if using AVD emulator)

```
10.0.2.2  - Special alias to your host loopback interface 
(i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)
```

For GenyMotion emulator the loopback address is **10.0.3.2**

Comment: Like this- 10.0.2.2/api Or 10.0.2.2:8000/api like this?

Comment: Please help me here too https://superuser.com/questions/1449269/how-can-i-address-my-emulator-to-my-localhost-with-my-ip-address?noredirect=1#comment2186484_1449269

Comment: @user145959 you should use `https://10.0.2.2` instaed `http://localhost` ... The IP address 192.168.x.x (indicates an address in the local network) has nothing to do with the loopback address so I am not sure why are you trying to use it in the first place.

Comment: @NickIliev: I changed my code like this export const `baseURL = "https://10.0.2.2:3000";` but didn't work. I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Emulator API Path:- http://10.0.2.2:5000. Like Your API Local Path Is http://198.168.1:5000/api or http://localhost:5000/api Then Replace With http://10.0.2.2:5000/api And Port Address Is Same Like As Your Local API Port.

Path- App_resources/Android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml :-

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" Add in application tag