# socket-io.clent does not work under React Native Android app

Tags: socket.io, react-native

I use socket-io.client library in ReactNative app. It works great on iOS but crashes android application.

Error in packager:

```
Directory ..node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\transports\index.j\lib\xmlhttprequest.js doesn't exist
```

> react-native-cli: 2.0.1 react-native: 0.40.0

I trying react-native 0.39 and get same error.

Comment: I have no specific code for this issue. Just install socket-io.client like a regular node module (npm install ..) in react project and trying import socket-io.client in js file. That's all

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, it is caused by how the library is imported.

```
var io = require("socket.io-client/dist/socket.io");
```

In your constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.socket = io('http://10.0.2.2:3000', { jsonp: false });
}
```

If you are using an Android emulator, use [10.0.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator-in-eclips) to connect to a node server running locally on your development machine.