# OkHttp cannot fetch data from localhost

Tags: android, kotlin

Can anyone please show me the way to fetch data from localhost by OkHttp in Kotlin. When i changed url to https, it worked well

Picture in Logcat for successful one

but when i use http://localhost..., it failed to execute

Picture when failed

Comment: Please improve the question and attached the picture again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to my http://localhost web server from Android Emulator in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator-in-eclips)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** - 8/23/22

It is likely you need to set

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

as a flag within the <application> element in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

**Old Answer**

don't use localhost like this. open command prompt if you are using Windows. type ipconfig and then get Local Ip Address and then use that Ip Address to get data from local host.
same method for Mac. you have to get local ip address

[image]