# DJI Android SDK bridge

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I working in a project with Phantom 4 advanced+, i downloaded the most recent android sdk version from github. i edited the code with the developer key that asks and run it in the android studio emulator. It asks WSBridge ip, but i have no idea how to find it. I did a lot of research and found different solutions, but none of them worked out for me. Already downloaded DJI Bridge that dji suggest and i followed the instructions step by step and still didn't found it.

Any information about how can i find it, or anything that you believe can solve my problem it would be very helpfull for me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to my http://localhost web server from Android Emulator in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator-in-eclips)

Comment: @MartinZeitler, This is DJI SDK specific "IP". So it is not a dup of your suggested thread. Thanks

Comment: @Talobin well, the whole DJI bridge seems to be redundant, because the claimed limit of a single one `adb` connection is not true; one can connect several devices at once, no matter through which interface. it's probably a little bit of shell scripting vs. adding clutter into the package, which can be prevented; still think it's ok, while only debug builds would be affected. or does it connect to the drone, too? just checked https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/

Comment: @MartinZeitler, 
 When use adb tcp, any USB connectivity events (plug in/plug out/ restart drone...) will drop this connection.Also, adb tcp connection will drops when there is network congestion. So for small project, this might not be a problem at all. For CI/CD of big project, the connection needs to be always alive. Another reason for wifi connection not being stable ( hence adb tcp will break)   is drones use wireless connection (from RC to drone). When one has 5,10 or much more in a testing warehouse, wifi will get so much interference that adb tcp will not work. 
Very drone specific..

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the BridgeApp in an actual Android phone (https://github.com/dji-sdk/Android-Bridge-App)
2. Connect the phone to RC and Wifi and make sure both left and right indicators are green.
3. On the bridgeapp screen, you should see IP address. That is the IP address you need to give SDK  for SDK to connect to BridgeApp.
4. Connect SDK to BridgeApp using the `enableBridgeModeWithBridgeAppIP` method inside SDKManager class.

-This is only if you want to use DJI SDK using Bridge mode. The benefit of this is in debugging, since the app that is running DJISDK can be run in a different phone than the phone that actually connects to the RC.
-If you don't need this, you don't have to use BridgeApp and Bridge mode of DJI SDK. Connect the phone that has DJI SDK app running directly to the RC and it should work.

Comment: Did you manage to make this app work? Mine one shows everything connect, but I can't communicate with the RC nor the aircraft