# Connect to localhost from android studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to connect from my app that runs under android studio.

in the app i have base_url : http://192.168.10.224/xxxxx/public/

I connect in the browser of the virtual device and fins the page I want, so I know that the address is right.

I start the app and come to the loginpage.

I type my variables and press sign in.

And I get this in log:

```
2020-11-21 18:23:25.682 27502-27795/com.xxxxxx.user D/OkHttp: --> POST http://localhost/xxxxxx/public/api/user/oauth/token
2020-11-21 18:23:25.682 27502-27795/com.xxxxxx.user D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
2020-11-21 18:23:25.704 27502-27795/com.xxxxxx.user D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/xxxxxx:80
```

Why can't I connect to localhost?

UPDATE: this is how I get in Android Studio

```
E/AAAA:  device token : 123456789
E/AAAA:  login: req: {"
password":"123456","
device_id":"123","
grant_type":"password","
device_token":"123456789","
device_type":"android","
client_secret":"111111111111","
client_id":"2","
username":"MYEMAIL"}
D/OkHttp: --> POST http://xxxxx/public/api/user/oauth/token
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Content-Length: 350
D/OkHttp: password=123456&device_id=123&grant_type=password&device_token=123456789&device_type=android&client_secret=111111111111&client_id=2&username=MYEMAIL
    --> END POST (350-byte body)
D/OkHttp: <-- 405 Method Not Allowed http://xxxxx/public/api/user/oauth/token (113ms)
```

Comment: Because localhost in this case is the phone, while you want to connect to your PC, use 192.168.10.224 instead of localhost

Comment: in the app i have http://192.168.10.224 instead of localhost, still i get <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/xxxxxx:80..i cant find anyweare in the code localhost.

Comment: Try to find the place in code where the request is made and figure out where the url comes from?

Comment: I cant find it :(

Comment: anyone that can have answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect to my http://localhost web server from Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator)

Comment: no it doesent help me.