# Failed to connect localhost from android emulator

Tags: java, android, asp.net-mvc, android-emulator

I have created rest api from .net. I have simple login and registration android application. Here is code where I bind local ip

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit instance;
    public static Retrofit getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://localhost:5000/")
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

When I run the application and test my login function it return

> Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:5000

How can I solve this issue

[image: emulator display]

[image: emulator setting]

Comment: are you sure with port number?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator)?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Yes I typed wrong output early I updated!

Comment: @MuhammadFarhan Yes I tried with my machine ip address which is 192.168.x.x something like that

Comment: Can you confirm what IP is being displayed in emulator. You can confirm this in emulator settings.

Comment: And please confirm what OS version you are using?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed added!

Comment: `Here is code where I bind local ip` No that code does not bind a socket to an ip. Instead it is code that tries to connect with a server on localhost. As every device or emulator is its own localhost that code (which runs on an emulator) tries to connect with a server running on that emulator too. Well did you install your server on your emulator?

Comment: @blackapps install server mean? I run server locally... API working fine I have tested using Postman

Comment: Locally? I have no idea where that would be. Locally on your emulator? Locally on your Android phone? Localhost is the device itself. Localhost is the emulator itself.

Comment: My API is localhost:5000 I need to connect my API with emulator

Answer (score 0):

You need create an xml and write below code in that xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">your sub domain</domain>
</domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

The location of the file should be as

** main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml**

And add this file in manifest in application tag as mentioned below:

```
<application
......
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
```

## Explanation:

Since localhost is not a secure domain, you must allow non-secured domains in your network configuration for API 28+ where non-TLS connections are prevented by default.

Comment: Not working same error I have replace 127.0.0.1 to second <domain>

Comment: try with local ip that is something like 192.168......

Comment: do I need to change emulator proxy setting currently I am set proxy to 127.0.0.1

Comment: when I use local ip and set proxy setting of emulator to no proxy. it return /192.168.x.x (port 5000) from /192.168.232.2 (port 43042

Comment: you are using local host or ip while using retrofit code?

Comment: I have tested both

Answer (score 0):

In my case server run on localhost means 127.0.0.1:5000. I have change this to my local IP address which is 192.168.x.x:5000 to run the server. Then it worked. Hope this will helpful.