# Adb reverse tcp not working on android emulator connected

Tags: flutter, android-studio, adb

I am trying to consume an api in flutter and I started getting an error on device emulator port in android studio

Which returns the following error:

[image]

I found a possible solution by executing a command called abd for example:

```
adb reverse tcp:33298 tcp:5554
```

After executing the command I try again from my emulator and I get the same problem

[image]

Comment: You are really trying to it the hard way don't you? If you have a service running on localhost on the host PC simply use `http://10.0.2.2` inside the emulator. [How to connect to my http://localhost web server from Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220)