# Android Emulator

Tags: android, emulation

I am using Nexus 5x API 27 for my Android project. How do I configure the emulator to communicate with localhost?

I have checked the emulator options but I can't find the proxy settings. Is there a new way of doing it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect to my http://localhost web server from Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806220/how-to-connect-to-my-http-localhost-web-server-from-android-emulator)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

find that in emulator settings menu

[image]

Comment: When I click on the extended controls>settings, I do not have the proxy settings tab, only Advanced which does not have any proxy settings either.

Comment: can you tell me version of your android studio?

Comment: the Android Version is Chipmunk 2021.2.1