# How to get .NET MAUI Android emulator connect to local docker node js server

Tags: c#, node.js, .net, docker, maui

I'm using Visual Studio's .NET Maui QEMU android emulator, and want it to make an HTTP request to my Node JS backend that's running on docker. How would I get it them to connect?

I've tried using localhost, the host machine's ip, etc, but I get a HTTP connection failure error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you try the steps in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75155196/12567640 ?